# Typo3 Neos: How to insert a form into a template

Tags: forms, typo3, yaml

Is it possible to insert a form build with TYPO3.Form into a template? I defined all needed fields in the .yaml file and would like to render this directly in the template and not insert it via the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if i understand you correctly, but in your Typoscript configuration you can specifiy nodetypes which will be rendered on the page. I needed to render a form in a footer on all sites, here's my working configuration:

**Root.ts2**

```
footerData {
        form = TYPO3.Neos.NodeTypes:Form {
            formIdentifier = "minimal-contact-form"
        }
}
```

**Default.html**

```
...

{footerData.form -> f:format.raw()}

...
```

**minimal-contact-form.yaml**

```
type: 'TYPO3.Form:Form'
identifier: minimal-contact-form
label: 'Minimal Contact form'
...
```